# Server Consume 47 %of RAM

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, process

I have server dual core with 2 gb of RAM and 2 website with no many traffic and the RAM it´s to 47 % , i have simple web in html and one wordpress with only some informations and nothing traffic

I do tests for put the server ok and i see the ram it´s over 47% , my server it´s in OVH

Actually i do some tests and show this process for apache , tell until i restart apache for example or mysql also and the ram consume go down , after this up other time

```
9218 root      20   0 15068 1236  884 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.18 top
22325 apache    20   0  521m  94m  37m S  0.3  4.8  10:49.06 httpd
22329 apache    20   0  520m  93m  37m S  0.3  4.7  10:39.32 httpd
    1 root      20   0 19272  328  148 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.01 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:56.34 ksoftirqd/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 331379:17 migration/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 333622:09 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   6:04.62 ksoftirqd/1
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 333716:04 migration/2
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:48.47 ksoftirqd/2
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 333992:48 migration/3
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:34.33 ksoftirqd/3
   17 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
   18 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   20 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
  409 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:42.24 sync_supers
  411 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.94 bdi-default
  412 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
  414 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
  533 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  543 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
  550 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md
  652 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod
  653 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kvm-irqfd-clean
  700 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  17:09.10 kswapd0
  701 root      25   5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
  702 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark
  706 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nfsiod
  711 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 jfsIO





22259 apache    20   0  533m 106m  37m S 67.4  5.4  11:23.94 httpd
22329 apache    20   0  519m  92m  37m S 48.1  4.7  10:51.54 httpd
22325 apache    20   0  521m  94m  37m R 38.5  4.8  10:59.66 httpd
19357 mysql     20   0 1635m  42m 3628 S  2.3  2.2 752:19.11 mysqld
22284 apache    20   0  537m 110m  37m S  0.7  5.6  11:41.85 httpd
32199 root      20   0  456m 6584 1088 S  0.7  0.3 333:46.41 ajenti-panel
 9218 root      20   0 15068 1236  884 R  0.3  0.1   0:01.80 top
22281 apache    20   0  528m 101m  37m S  0.3  5.1  12:23.11 httpd
22343 apache    20   0  522m  95m  37m S  0.3  4.8  11:40.06 httpd
28857 root      20   0 19296  356  232 S  0.3  0.0   0:14.25 dovecot
    1 root      20   0 19272  328  148 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.01 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:56.34 ksoftirqd/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 331379:17 migration/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 333622:09 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   6:04.62 ksoftirqd/1
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 333716:04 migration/2
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:48.49 ksoftirqd/2
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 333992:48 migration/3
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:34.35 ksoftirqd/3
   17 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
   18 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   20 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
  409 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:42.24 sync_supers
  411 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.94 bdi-default
  412 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
  414 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
  533 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  543 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
  550 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md
```

I don´t know why i see when use top for see the process , why i see many process of apache when no running websites for example and i need help for fix this , also comment in other server i have in OVH i have server for testes and no have websites and always show 20 % of RAM in use , i don´t know why happend this

Also comment this in configuration of apache i have this :

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

With free -m

```
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1980       1929         51          0         94        790
-/+ buffers/cache:       1043        936
Swap:          510        100        410
```

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: 1. Why is this a problem? 2. What's the real memory use? `top` is useless for this. Post the output of `free -m`. 3. Have you read http://www.linuxatemyram.com/?

Comment: with free -m tell me this  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1980       1929         51          0         94        790
-/+ buffers/cache:       1043        936
Swap:          510        100        410

Comment: NO duplicate man it´s the first time i come here it´s my first post

Comment: @Fran: Duplicate means that the problem has already been answered in another question. Have you *read* the linked question?

Answer (score 0):

Running PHP on a LWP (threads) server? That's brave.

MaxRequestsPerChild = 0? That's......errrr.....very brave?

I for one would be very interested in an analysis of the performance and stability of your system.

Did you read the metrics you published? While looking at the memory usage of a single process gives a very misleading picture of what memory it actually consumes (even for a program which runs as a single process - forking/LWP processes are even more skewed) it's fairly clear from what you've presented here that MySQL is using the majority of the memory.

If the site is heavily data-oriented and the data is in an inodb back-end then that is as it should be.

Even if it's grabbing too much memory, I wouldn't expect this to be having a huge impact on performance - hence reducing the size of the buffer pool might make the statistics you are currently measuring look more healthy - but it's unlikely to affect the performance of the system much.

It looks like there's a lot of scope for tuning the Apache installation too.